# RedBeanPHP not saving strings correctly, skips from an accented vowel onwards

Tags: php, redbean

I'm trying to save some simple PHP objects using RedBeanPHP. It works fine, except that on string fields, it reaches a point where there is an accented vowel, ie `á` or 'í' and just skips the rest of the remaining characters in the string.

Example:

```
// Actual string in PHP script.
Esta es una frase mía y me gusta!

// Saved to database.
Esta es una frase m
```

Here's my PHP script:

```
// Setup RedBean to work with a database.
R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=noticias','root','');

foreach($parsedNews as &$tmpNews) {
    $noticia = R::dispense('noticia');
    $noticia->imagen = $tmpNews->get_image();
    $noticia->fecha = $tmpNews->get_fechanoticia();
    $noticia->titulo = $tmpNews->get_title();
    $noticia->url = $tmpNews->get_sourceurl();
    $noticia->descripcion = $tmpNews->get_description(); 
    $id = R::store($noticia);  
}
```

Comment: I don't know redbean, but it looks like a encoding issue. Is that connection string a dsn string for PDO?

Comment: @PeeHaa: I don't know, from the documentation on RedBean: `RedBeanPHP only works with the InnoDB driver for MySQL.`

Comment: @PeeHaa: I created my database with `collation` in PhpMyAdmin. Should I use `utfbin`? edit: Even with utf8bin, the problem remains.

Comment: Use utf8-unicode-ci or utf8-bin if you want case sensitivity.

Comment: Aside: I recommend you don't use the writeback `&` in your `foreach`. If you were later on to have another loop that writes to `$tmpNews`, or otherwise reset this variable, you'd overwrite the last item in the `$parsedNews` array.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct answer is that the source encoding is not actually UTF8.

```
 $bean->property = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", "Esta es una frase mía y me gusta!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your database table collations to UTF-8. (utf8-unicode-ci is probably what you want).

Comment: Tried it, and still no dice. No characters after an accent is saved at all.

Comment: Weird...are you sure redbean supports UTF-8?

Comment: Also, you aren't the only person with this issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/redbeanorm/bCmJ-WqHRWk

Comment: Following that link, `Sounds like an iconv issue. It's known to truncate any remaining 
output when it encounters a char that it can't handle. ` How exactly can I apply that in context? What does that mean?